# Transact sql query perfomance advice

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have 2 select queries. The first performs selection for grid paging(25 rows per page) (`using TOP @pagesize*@pagenum EXCEPT TOP @pagesize*(@pagenum-1) construction`). Second query total count of rows.

So, will `WITH AS` construction increase performance versus two separated queries, if so why? Note, that query contains multiple columns, INNER JOINs and WHERE conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. WITH part for itself does not help performance. It makes the query easier to understand.
2. If I understand correctly, the count is for all the rows. You can save the second call if you get all the rows to the client, but in most cases it will be more expensive.
3. Using top X to get only the last X/Y rows is a bad idea. You should do add an auto number and select the rows where the auto number is in the desired range.

   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Something] DESC) FROM ...
   WHERE [RowNumber] BETWEEN 10 AND 20

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you use ORDER BY ... OFFSET instead of TOP ... ORDER BY you can use COUNT(*) OVER () to get all rows regardless of paging. Else you have to isolate your data using WITH (as you do) and get paging with the 2nd table as well as anything else (row number, page, total pages and so on.

Example without offset:

```
    DECLARE @page INT = 1, @rows INT = 5

    ;WITH data AS  (SELECT * FROM mytable where  id = 454545) --possible filters

          ,rows ([page], [pages], [rows]) AS
          (
          SELECT @page, CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS float)/@rows), COUNT(*) FROM data
          )
          SELECT TOP (@rows) *
          FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY data.id) rowNumber, * FROM rows, data ) pagination
          WHERE rowNumber > (@page - 1) * @rows
          order by rowNumber
```

Example with offset:

```
DECLARE @page INT = 1, @rows INT = 5

    SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (order by id ) rowNumber,@page Page,(CEILING(CasT(COUNT(*) OVER () as float)/@rows)) Pages,
    COUNT(*) OVER () Rows, *

    from mytable where  id = 454545 --possible filters
    order by rowNumber 
    OFFset (@page-1)*@rows rows 
    FETCH NEXT @rows rows ONLY
```

In both cases make sure the order by is absolute else your paging is not guaranteed